# Deserialize JSON with comma-separated values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I want to de-serialize a JSON where a node contains values which comma-separated. But the object which contains the comma returns null when deserializing.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "SolutionTabletSubSectionUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "SolutionTabletSubSectionId": 1,
  "SolutionTabletUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "Title": "string",
  "SubTitle": "string",
  "Description": "string",
  "Link": "www.google.com,www.facebook.com",
  "LinkDisplayName": "DisplayName1,DisplayName2",
  "SolutionTabletConfigurationUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "SolutionTabletTemplateUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "ImageName": "string",
  "ImagePath": "string",
  "DisplayOrderId": 0,
  "TemplateComponentUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "FooterTitle": "string",
  "FooterDescription": "string"
}
```

Code:

```cs
var list = new List<MyList>();
list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(input));
MySubClass resultSet = new MySubClass();
resultSet.Data = list;
```

MyClass:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid SolutionTabletSubSectionUId { get; set; }
    public int SolutionTabletSubSectionId { get; set; }
    public string LinkDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public List<LinkNamesNode> LinkNames { get; set; }
}

public class LinkNamesNode
{
    public string LinkDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

While debugging, I can see `LinkNames` is set to null or not hitting because the property name is not found. Please help me here to deserialize an object.

My output should look like:

```
{
  "LoggedInUser": "string",
  "Data": [
    {
      "SolutionTabletSubSectionUId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "SolutionTabletSubSectionId": 0
      "LinkNames": [
        {
          "LinkDisplayName": "DisplayName1",
          "Link": "www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "LinkDisplayName": "DisplayName2",
          "Link": "www.facebook.com"
        }
      ]
  ]
}
```

Please assist.

Comment: Do your `Link` and `LinkDisplayName` guarantee has the same length after split by separator?

Comment: Serialization may not be the best fit here. Your properties have comma-separated values. What you can do is serialize your json with the current shape. Split the values by commas and build the list from the split values then you can assign the `LinkNames` property and serialize your model again.

Comment: @YongShun, No it may differ in length

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the JSON as JSON rather than as a string literal with escaping? You could then format it in a readable way rather than having it on a single line. At the moment it's really hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [`JsonConstructorAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) to implement the custom deserialization logic.

Since mentioned that the size of `Link` and `LinkDisplayName` may differ in length after split by separator:

1. Get the max value between the `links` and `linkDisplayNames` arrays.
2. Get the value from the array by index **safely** with `Array.ElementAtOrDefault(i)` method. And add the object to the `LinkNames` array.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(Guid solutionTabletSubSectionUId, int solutionTabletSubSectionId, string linkDisplayName, string link)
    {
        SolutionTabletSubSectionUId = solutionTabletSubSectionUId;
        SolutionTabletSubSectionId = solutionTabletSubSectionId;
        LinkDisplayName = linkDisplayName;
        Link = link;
        LinkNames = new List<LinkNamesNode>();
        
        string[] links = new string[] {};
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(link))
            links = link.Split(',').ToArray();
        
        string[] linkDisplayNames = new string[] {};
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linkDisplayName))
            linkDisplayNames = linkDisplayName.Split(',').ToArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(links.Length, linkDisplayNames.Length); i++)
        {
            LinkNames.Add(new LinkNamesNode
                          {
                              Link = links.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
                              LinkDisplayName = linkDisplayNames.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
                          });
        }
    }
    
    public Guid SolutionTabletSubSectionUId { get; set; }

    public int SolutionTabletSubSectionId { get; set; }

    public string LinkDisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public List<LinkNamesNode> LinkNames { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VypfKK)

Comment: This works like a charm. Learned a new thing today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem with an intermediate object because the structures of two side is not the same.

1. create a temp class:

   public class MyTempClass
   {
   public Guid SolutionTabletSubSectionUId { get; set; }
   public int SolutionTabletSubSectionId { get; set; }

   ```
       public string Link;

       public string LinkDisplayName;

       public  MyClass ConverToMyClass()
       {
           MyClass c = new MyClass();
           c.LinkNames = new List<LinkNamesNode>();
           c.SolutionTabletSubSectionId = this.SolutionTabletSubSectionId;
           c.SolutionTabletSubSectionUId = this.SolutionTabletSubSectionUId;
           List<string> links = this.Link.Split(",").ToList();
           List<string> linkNames = this.LinkDisplayName.Split(",").ToList();
           for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
           {
               c.LinkNames.Add(new LinkNamesNode()
               { Link = links[i], LinkDisplayName = linkNames[i] });
           }

           return c;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change your code to this:

string input = File.ReadAllText("C:\working_dir\stackoverflows\jsonserialize\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\jsconfig1.json");
MyTempClass result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
MyClass myClass = result.ConverToMyClass();

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a json converter

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, new StringConverter());

public class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var l = ((string)jObj["Link"]).Split(",");

        var result = jObj.ToObject<MyClass>();
        result.LinkNames = ((string)jObj["LinkDisplayName"]).Split(",")
                            .Zip(l, (k, v) => new LinkNamesNode { LinkDisplayName = k, Link = v })
                            .ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyClass);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and remove these properties from your class, you don' t need them

```
    public string LinkDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
```